# Independence of MLEs of 2 parameter exponential, and showing functions of them are chi-square

Tags: self-study, maximum-likelihood, independence, estimators, chi-squared-distribution

> Consider a random sample of size $n$ from a two-parameter exponential distribution, $X_i \sim $EXP($\theta,\eta$), and let $\eta^*$ and $\theta^*$ be the MLEs.
>
> a) Show that $\eta^*$ and $\theta^*$ are independent.
>
> b) Let $V_1=2n(\overline{X}-\eta)/\theta$, $V_2=2n(\eta^*-eta)/\theta$, and $V_3=2n\theta^*/\theta$.  Show that $V_1 \sim \chi^2(2n)$, $V_2 \sim \chi^2(2)$, and $V_3 \sim \chi^2(2n-2)$. *Hint:* Note that $V_1=V_2+V_3$ and that $V_2$ and $V_3$ are independent.  Find the MGF of $V_3$.

So I'm not really sure how to do part a) at all, and for part b), I know I can just show $V_2$ and $V_3$ and then add them to get $V_1$, but I'm not really sure how to get those 2.  I'm assuming you somehow use the rule that if $X \sim \Gamma(\alpha,\beta)$ then $2X/\beta \sim \chi^2(2\alpha)$ but I'm not sure how to apply that.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2764443/321264 might help.

Comment: That helps somewhat.  I still don't know how to do part a) though.

Comment: The comment was intended to help solve part (a). It has been highlighted in [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/272509/119261) answer as well. Have you found the MLEs?

Comment: I have $X_{(1)}$ as the MLE for $\eta$ and $\sum(X_i-X_{(1)})/n$ for $\theta$.

Comment: Yes, if $\eta$ and $\theta$ are the location and scale parameters respectively. You have to slightly generalize the setup in the linked threads to show independence of the MLEs.