# The difference of $\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_{i}$ and $\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_{(i)}$

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, order-statistics

Here is a exercise from *Mathematical Statistics. Jun Shao. Second edition. EX2.20

Let $X_1,..., X_n$ be $i.i.d.$ random variables having the exponential distribution $E(a,\theta)$, $a\in R$, and $\theta > 0$.

$$
      f(x,a,\theta)=\frac{1}{\theta}e^{-(x-a)/\theta}I(x>a)
$$

$$
      F(x)=1-e^{-(x-a)/\theta}
$$

Show that the smallest order statistic, $X_{(1)}$, has the exponential distribution $E(a,\theta/n)$ and that $2\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}(X_{i}-X_{(1)})/\theta$ has the chi-square distribution $\chi^2_{2n-2}$.

What I know is:

The p.d.f. of $X_{(1)}$ is:
$$
     f(x)=\frac{n!}{(n-1)!}\left[\frac{1}{\theta}e^{-(x-a)/\theta}\right]\left[e^{-(x-a)/\theta}\right]^{n-1}=\frac{1}{\theta/n}\exp\left\{-\frac{x-a}{\theta/n}\right\}\sim E(a,\theta/n)
$$

I don't know how to caculate the p.d.f. of $2\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}(X_{i}-X_{(1)})/\theta$ ;

But I know how to caculate the p.d.f. of $2\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}(X_{(i)}-X_{(1)})/\theta$ .

My question is that can we assume $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}X_{i}$ and $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}X_{(i)}$ are the same?

If we can not, can you give one example to explain? and how to solve the question above.

Comment: Original problem discussed at https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/272385/119261.

Comment: > *I don't know how to caculate the p.d.f. of* $$2\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}(X_{i}-X_{(1)})/\theta$$ 

*> But I know how to caculate the p.d.f. of* $$2\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}(X_{(i)}-X_{(1)})/\theta$$This is exactly the trick, use the [memoryless](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memorylessness) property of the exponential distribution, well done.

Comment: > *But I know how to caculate the p.d.f. of* $$2\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}(X_{(i)}-X_{(1)})/\theta$$ Here you actually use the same principle as the one that you are asking for. The sum of ordered exponentially distributed variables $(X_{(i)}-X_{(1)})$ is similar to the sum of unordered exponentially distributed variables.

Comment: If you shuffle a deck of cards, the sum of the numbered cards is the same every time. It’s also the same if you sort the cards.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**:  If the data is $X_1, X_2, \dotsc, X_n$ and its order statistics is
$X_{(1)} \le X_{(2)} \le \dotsm \le X_{(n)}$, can you explain that the order stats is simply some permutation of the data $X_i$ in its original order, that the two collections are equal *as sets*, so the sum must be the same?

$1 +2+3$ is the same as $1+3+2$.

Comment: When we observe the data, we can know the  $\sum X_{i}$ is equal to the $\sum X_{(i)}$. But $X_{i}$ and $X_{(i)}$ are random variables, I am still a little confused.

Comment: But whatever is the data, the same argument can be made. There is no possibility of an outcome where the result does not hold.

Comment: I think I know what confused me. For $X_{i}$ and $X_{(i)}$, they have different distribution. But for $\sum X_{i}$ and $\sum X_{(i)}$, they have the same distribution. And $X_{i}$ are i.i.d. but $X_{(i)}$ are not independent.